# iOS Camera Usage Policy invisable camera monitoring

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I know iOS 4 released more control over the camera but I can't seem to find any info on the usage policy.

Specifically, I would like to monitor a video stream with a computer vision algorithm from the front camera without the user having to grant us access to the the camera every time the app runs.

Is this possible/acceptable for usage in the App Store?

thanks

Comment: You're obviously not going to accept my answer of "Absolutely not.", so I deleted it. Maybe someone else will convince you.

Comment: comments from the apple developer forum suggest you can. it's not restricted and the AvCam demo provides a test bed where you can observe the frame data without displaying it to or prompting the user.

Answer (score 2):

It's against the law. In some countries - for sure. [Even Wiki knows.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photography_and_the_law) You can't take the video or photos without permission. Is it possible with current iOS frameworks? Maybe. Is it ok for being in Appstore? Sure, not. But, if you will write additional user agreement for itunesconnect and it will be something like "we will take video of you siting in the toilet using our app, don't be shy!" or something else legal enough to be approved by Apple, it may work.

Comment: Sorry. I was not completely clear. I don't want to show the video stream to anyone. I want to silently be able to use it for a CV application.

Comment: That's what you need to say in user agreement. It can be placed in itunesconnect or, maybe, in the app and you will show it to user at the first launch. I am still not sure about technical possibilities of such trick with video, but I think Apple will not be against the safe app that uses camera for some reason without recording or sending video. But, if you use any private API to achieve it, app will be rejected anyway, because it's forbidden.